# Running Command in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, csh

I am trying to execute a opencl program by running the command in a shell script.
When , I run the command on the command line it runs without any errors.
But when I run it in a shell script it throws error -

```
icpc command not found
```

Here is my shell script

```
#!/bin/csh

foreach t (1024 4096 8192 32768 50000 100000 500000 1000000 2000000 3000000 4000000 5000000 6000000 7000000 8000000)
        foreach l (8 16 32 64 128 256 512)
                icpc -o first first.cpp  -no-vec /scratch/cuda-7.0/lib64/libOpenCL.so -lm -openmp -DNMB=$t -DLOCAL_SIZE=$l
                ./first
        end
end
```

Can anyone please help me fix it

Comment: Specify  full path to icpc in your shell script

Comment: It seems `icpc` is not under your environmental path. Try to use absolute path for `icpc`

Comment: You know this it not bash right? You are using csh shell. Which she'll is your default (in terminal)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify full path to icpc in your shell script – algor